# load url without refreshing..how to do?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

After some scouring I came across this html 5 code

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

but how do you introduce it? how would I use such a code to change the url to http://google.com without refreshing the page? how about a link or button that would do this?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), you won't be able to change the URL to http://www.google.com/ unless the page attempting to make the change is on www.google.com. It'd be a tremendous security risk.